# Creating a class based JS instead of id

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have created this javascript that animates a certain place using it's ID.
The problem is that there are many of those on the site and meaning this I'd have to duplicate this function a lot of times just to replace the x in getElementById("x").

So here is the code I fully done by myself:

```
    var popcount = 0;
var opanumber = 1;
var poptimeout;
function pop() {
    if (popcount < 10) {
        popcount++;
        if (opanumber == 1) {
        document.getElementById("nav1").style.opacity = 0;
        opanumber = 0;
        poptimeout = setTimeout("pop()", 50);
        }
        else {
        document.getElementById("nav1").style.opacity = 1;
        opanumber = 1;
        poptimeout = setTimeout("pop()", 50);
        }
    }
    else {
    popcount = 0;
    document.getElementById("nav1").style.opacity = 1;
    }
}

function stoppop() {
    clearTimeout(poptimeout);
    popcount = 0;
    document.getElementById("nav1").style.opacity = 1;
}
```

I would gladly appreciate any information on how I could solve this situation and also any tutorials about using classes and "this".

Comment: well for one, you already realized the problem, the fact that you hardcoded `nav1` parameter. Now, I am assuming you also know how you can add parameters to your functions, Those parameters you can then reuse in your functions. Another thing you should think about, setTimeout with a string approach is concidered a very dated aproach, just define an anonymous function and call your pop function from within that anonymous function. Another small point, as this is working code, [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) might be a better location for your question

Comment: Adding a parameter to my function would make it work (I tried it), but I can't seem to be able to getElementById of the parameter. Tried '"' + p1 + '"'.
As for the setTimeout might work, but I'd need the function id for onmouseover, no?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this; rather than hard code a value into a function it is better to pass the value in so you can reuse the function on more than one thing. In this case you can now call startPop and stopPop with the name of a CSS class.

```
var popTimeout;

function setOpacity(className, value) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(
        document.getElementsByClassName(className), 
        function(el) {
            el.style.opacity = value;
        }
    );
}

function pop(className, popCount, opaNumber) {
    if (popCount < 10) { //Must be even number so you end on opacity = 1
        setOpacity(className, opaNumber);
        popTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
            pop(className, popCount++, 1-opaNumber);
        }, 50);
    }
}

function startPop(className) {
    pop(className, 0, 0);
}

function stopPop(className) {
    clearTimeout(popTimeout);
    setOpacity(className, 1);
}
```

In case you are wondering about the `1 - opaNumber;` this is a simpler way of switching a value between 1 and 0. As 1-1=0 and 1-0=1.

Comment: Thanks, but I get "Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).forEach is not a function" after setting up the class and fitting the code in. ;/

Comment: You will need something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/2b9304ur/ https://toddmotto.com/ditch-the-array-foreach-call-nodelist-hack/

Comment: Damm node lists not supporting forEach. Try it now.

Comment: @sinisake is `use strict` not enough? with `document.querySelectorAll` foreach works perfectly fine

Comment: @Icepickle, yep, it seems so (not in IE11, though).

Comment: I'm wondering is you can do `for(el in document.getElementsByClassName(className))`

Comment: I actually think I'd use Id's, because the navigation button is unique and I need only one "poping" onmouseover. I was talking about classes, because I thought that using this it would be possible to get the correct place and work the style on that.

I hope you understand me. ;)

Comment: @DavidBradshaw No, I don't think so, as el would be a property on the expression (so, '0', '1', etc...)

Comment: @MrMeDo it would be easy enough to change it back to using IDs, if your learning to code I think it would be a good exercise for you to try. Between my answer and your question you have everything you need. Just pass ID instead of className and make the setOpacity function use what you had to start with.

Comment: @DavidBradshaw Yep, I'll manage mate ;). Only thing I'm considering now is who to give best answear to @_@.

Answer (score 1):

Well you started out with recognizing where you have the problem and that's already a good thing :)

To make your code a bit more compact, and get as many things as possible out of the local scope, you could check the following implementation.

It is in a sense a small demo, where I tried adding as much comments as possible.

I edited a bit more after realizing you rather want to use classnames instead of id's :) As a result, I am now rather using the [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) that gives you a bit more freedom.

Now you can call the startPop function with any valid selector. If you want to pop purely on ID, you can use:

```
startPop('#elementId');
```

or if you want to go for classes

```
startPop('.className');
```

The example itself also add's another function, nl trigger, that shows how you can start / stop the functions.

I also opted to rather use the `setInterval` method instead of the `setTimeout` method. Both callback a function after a certain amount of milliseconds, however setInterval you only have to call once.

As an extra change, stopPop also now uses the `document.querySelectorAll` so you have the same freedom in calling it as the `startPop` function.

I added 2 more optional parameters in the startPop function, namely `total` and `callback`.

Total indicates the maximum times you wish to "blink" the element(s), and the callback provides you with a way to get notified when the popping is over (eg: to update potential elements that started the popping)

I changed it a bit more to allow you to use it for hovering over an element by using the `this` syntax for inline javascript

```js
'use strict';

function getElements( className ) {
  // if it is a string, assume it's a selector like #id or .className
  // if not, assume it's an element
  return typeof className === "string" ? document.querySelectorAll( className ) : [className];
}

function startPop(className, total, callback) {
  // get the element once, and asign a value
  var elements = getElements( className ),
    current = 0;
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    var opacity = ++current % 2;
    // (increase current and set style to the left over part after dividing by 2)
    elements.forEach(function(elem) { elem.style.opacity = opacity } );
    // check if the current value is larger than the total or 10 as a fallback
    if (current > (total || 10)) {
      // stops the current interval
      stopPop(interval, className);
      // notifies that the popping is finished (if you add a callback function)
      callback && callback();
    }
  }, 50);
  // return the interval so it can be saved and removed at a later time
  return interval;
}

function stopPop(interval, className) {
  // clear the interval
  clearInterval(interval);
  // set the opacity to 1 just to be sure ;)
  getElements( className ).forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.style.opacity = 1;
  });
}

function trigger(eventSource, className, maximum) {
  // get the source of the click event ( the clicked button )
  var source = eventSource.target;
  // in case the attribute is there
  if (!source.getAttribute('current-interval')) {
    // start it & save the current interval
    source.setAttribute('current-interval', startPop(className, maximum, function() {
      // completed popping ( set the text correct and remove the interval )
      source.removeAttribute('current-interval');
      source.innerText = 'Start ' + source.innerText.split(' ')[1];
    }));
    // change the text of the button
    source.innerText = 'Stop ' + source.innerText.split(' ')[1];
  } else {
    // stop it
    stopPop(source.getAttribute('current-interval'), className);
    // remove the current interval
    source.removeAttribute('current-interval');
    // reset the text of the button
    source.innerText = 'Start ' + source.innerText.split(' ')[1];
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="nav1">
  test navigation
</div>
<div class="nav2">
  Second nav
</div>
<div class="nav1">
  second test navigation
</div>
<div class="nav2">
  Second second nav
</div>
<a id="navigation-element-1" 
   onmouseover="this.interval = startPop( this )" 
   onmouseout="stopPop( this.interval, this )">Hover me to blink</a>

<button type="button" onclick="trigger( event, '.nav1', 100)">
  Start nav1
</button>
<button type="button" onclick="trigger( event, '.nav2', 100)">
  Start nav2
</button>
```

Comment: I'm still curious about the downvote (though I admit, I understood the question falsely at first, I think I added / corrected enough)

Comment: So basically I don't want many let's say div's to "pop" when onmouseover(in my situation), just the one. So the Id's might work as well. I actually came up with my way through this all after getting to know that you can actually get a variable for the Id just doing for example onmouseover="pop('nav1')". All I had to do is use those ' there.
The thing now is that on function timeout that value changes to "undefined" meaning the function is useless the second time. So i guess I'll have to do a different way with the timeout right?

Comment: @MrMeDo Yeah, you should check to use an anonymous function, in some ways like I used in the setInterval, as you already have the parameter defined in your pop function, you can reuse that value when calling the setTimeout method, however, my version would also work for your plan (and both with id's as classes ;))

Comment: @MrMeDo I added an option to use the script for hovering as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to take it back to using IDs, then you will need to think about `popTimeout` if you run this on more than one element at a time.

```
function setOpacity(id, value) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.opacity = value;
}

function runPop(id) {
    function pop(id, popCount, opaNumber) {
        if (popCount < 10) { //Must be even number so you end on opacity = 1
            setOpacity(id, opaNumber);
            popTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                pop(id, popCount++, 1-opaNumber);
            }, 50);
        }
    }

    var popTimeout;

    pop(id, 0, 0);

    return function() {
        clearTimeout(popTimeout);
        setOpacity(id, 1);
    }
}

var killPop = [];

function startPop(id) {
    killPop[id] = runPop(id);
}

function stopPop(id) {
    killPop[id]();
}
```